¿Como decirle al compilador que partes del código compilar y cuáles no en C++?
Tengo una clase que es friend de otra clase y dependiendo del proyecto esta clase friend a veces es requerida y a veces no, entonces cuando reutilizo el código entre los diferentes proyectos para no estar modificando el código cada vez, simplemente quiero decirle al compilador que si está definida la clase amiga que la compile y si no está definida, pues no.
// Esta es la clase que esta en todos los proyectos
class Person{
    int id_;
    std::string name_;
    std::string lastname_;
public:
    // y esta clase a veces es requerida y a veces no
    friend class PersonRepository;
};

Entonces mi pregunta y duda es... si es posible decirle al compilador que si no existe la clase PersonRepository que no compile esa linea de codigo (donde se define PersonRepository como clase amiga de Person), pero en el caso de que si existe que compile normalmente.

Sí, es posible indicarle al compilador que compile condicionalmente la declaración de clase amiga PersonRepository para la clase Person en función de si la clase PersonRepository está definida o no. Existen dos métodos principales para lograr esto:
1. Directivas de compilación condicional:

Utilizando #ifdef y #endif:

#ifdef PERSONREPOSITORY
// Declarar PersonRepository como clase amiga de Person
friend class PersonRepository;
#endif

En este caso, el compilador solo incluirá la declaración de clase amiga si la macro PersonRepository está definida. Si la macro no está definida, la declaración se omitirá.

Utilizando #if y #endif:

#if defined(PERSONREPOSITORY)
// Declarar PersonRepository como clase amiga de Person
friend class PersonRepository;
#endif

Este enfoque funciona de manera similar al anterior, pero utiliza la directiva #if para verificar si la macro PersonRepository está definida antes de incluir la declaración de clase amiga.
2. Plantillas de clase:

Utilizando plantillas de clase parciales:

template <typename T>
class Person {
public:
    // ... miembros de la clase Person ...
#ifdef PersonRepository
    friend class T;
#endif
};

// Definición de la clase Person completa
template <>
class Person<PersonRepository> {
public:
    // ... miembros de la clase Person específicos para PersonRepository ...
};

En este caso, la plantilla de clase Person define la declaración de clase amiga condicionalmente dentro de una sección #ifdef. La definición completa de la clase se proporciona en una especialización de plantilla para la clase PersonRepository, si está definida.

Idealmente la macro no debería llamarse igual que la clase.

Eso no lo sabía. Gracias por la corrección.

Si la macro PersonRepository estuviese definida, digamos que #define PersonRepository 1, seguramente friend class PersonRepository; sería reemplazado por friend class 1;
